# I want to emulate a mobile browser. How to implement it using Page.ClientTarget?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Based on the MSDN link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx

Assuming I want to see how my page will look like on safari or mobile firefox, how do I implement it using Page.ClientTarget?

I can't seem to find any good resources for this API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design), that way you are not relying on the `ClientTarget`, but rather on the size of the browser.

Responsive Design basically means your design adapts to the size of the screen ... so tablets and phones can have different views of the same page.

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is a decent place to start, but there are other frameworks.